# Data loss after ubuntu 16.03 install

Tags: hard-drive

I installed  Ubuntu 16.03 over Windows 7 using a DVD burned from a downloaded iso. My C drive vanished with all its data. I have looked at the 1.0 TB DISK where I think the drive and data might be. I can see partitions, but I can't see my old drive or data, and I don't know what to do with the partitions.
Thanks for any help
David Chadwick. dlchadwick@cox.net

Comment: I assume you mean 16.04.  Can you edit your question and add some information about the partitions?  Depending on the choices you made during install you may indeed have wiped out Windows.

Answer (score 1):

you can mount the  partitions  and get your data simply by typing :

```
sudo fdisk -l (it will list all the partitions on your hard disk)
sudo mount /dev/sda(disk number) /mnt(where you will find all your data)
```

you can create different directorys if you have many partitions for
exp:

```
mkdir ~/sda(partition number)
```

then you type :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda(partition number) ~/sda(partition number)
```